# ActionBarDisappearing on Android 4.0+

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am currently writing an application for devices on 2.3 - 4.2+ and am having some weird, and unexpected issues. It was working fine until and displaying on all devices before I attempted to theme it. Even with a simple style simply extending the action bar sherlock theme, there appears to be no action bar showing.

The setup for the styles.

```
<style name="FrameworkRoot.Theme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 11+ (compatibility) -->
    <item name="buttonBarStyle">@style/Compat.ButtonBar</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/Compat.ButtonBarButton</item>
    <item name="indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/Compat.IndeterminateProgress</item>
    <!-- API 14+ (compatibility) -->
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_padding_left</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_padding_right</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">@dimen/compat_list_preferred_item_height_small</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Base" parent="FrameworkRoot.Theme">
    <item name="textHeaderMaxLines">@integer/text_header_max_lines</item>
    <item name="trackAbstractMaxLines">@integer/track_abstract_max_lines</item>
    <item name="activatableItemBackground">@drawable/activatable_item_background</item>
</style>    

<!-- Base themes for the app -->
<style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.Base">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.TestApp.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.TestApp.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Base Action Bar Style -->
<style name="Widget.TestApp.ActionBar" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
```

If I remove the:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.TestApp.ActionBar</item>
```

So that the action bar itself it not getting styled in 3.0+, I can't style the bar.

What would be the best way to set this up? AndroidManifest.xml is pointing the app's style at "Theme.TestApp".

My end goal is to have a custom background on the action bar, as well as custom tab selector colors and fonts. What would be the best way to go about this, as my current method isn't working well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set an attribute for ActionBarSherlock *and* the native ActionBar. So replace this for example:

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="FrameworkRoot.Theme">
    <item name="textHeaderMaxLines">@integer/text_header_max_lines</item>
    <item name="trackAbstractMaxLines">@integer/track_abstract_max_lines</item>
    <item name="activatableItemBackground">@drawable/activatable_item_background</item>
</style>
```

With this:

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="FrameworkRoot.Theme">

    <item name="textHeaderMaxLines">@integer/text_header_max_lines</item>
    <item name="trackAbstractMaxLines">@integer/track_abstract_max_lines</item>
    <item name="activatableItemBackground">@drawable/activatable_item_background</item>

    <item name="android:textHeaderMaxLines">@integer/text_header_max_lines</item>
    <item name="android:trackAbstractMaxLines">@integer/track_abstract_max_lines</item>
    <item name="android:activatableItemBackground">@drawable/activatable_item_background</item>

</style>
```

The attributes with the 'android' prefix point to the internal resources for the native ActionBar, the attributes without the 'android' in front point to the resources of the ActionBarSherlock.